# Unable to define a Task using continueWith for a StreamDownloadTask

Tags: android, kotlin, task, firebase-storage, continuations

I'm trying to write a function in Kotlin that needs to return a `Bitmap` after getting a stream from a `StorageReference` object. Since I can't use a solution that implements listeners I have to define a `Continuation` and get the result when the `StreamDownloadTask` is completed.

The following is my not working attempt

```
fun getAdImg(imgId: String): Bitmap? {
        return storage.child(FOLDER).child(imgId+EXTENSION).stream.continueWith(Continuation<StreamDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot, Bitmap>() {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it.result)
        })

    }
```

I cannot understand how to define the `Continuation` object as there are no examples anywhere using basic types. I guess I have to override the `then` function and check if the `Task` has been completed in order to fetch the result.

EDIT1:
The error says:

`Type mismatch. Required: Bitmap? Found: Task<Bitmap!>`

Comment: Are you saying that what you have written now doesn't work?  Is there an error message?  Please edit the question to be specific.  If you're trying to make the download synchronous and return the converted bitmap value from getAdImg, that's not going to work at all.  You will have to use a callback or coroutine.

Comment: Type mismatch Required: Bitmap? Found: Task<Bitmap!>

Comment: You will need to use that Task asynchronously.  There is no avoiding that.  You will not be able to make the function return a Bitmap unless you make the method block, which is probably a bad idea.  This is what callbacks and coroutines are for.

Comment: My idea was to make this function as a `suspend function` since it will be launched from a view model scope but I need it to return the result I need but I'm not able to

Comment: OK, if you want to make this a suspend fun, then go ahead and do that, then update the question with what you've tried that doesn't work, along with an explanation.

Comment: As I said I'm not able to return a `Bitmap` since I have no clue on how to create the `Continuation` object inside the `continueWith` function

Comment: If your goal is to create an asynchronous suspend fun, then your question should be updated to state that goal.  I've already said that it's a bad idea to try to return the Bitmap synchronously, given that the Firebase APIs are all asynchronous.  If you **do** want to create a suspend fun, then a continuation isn't necessary here at all.  You can use the play services task adapter. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

Comment: I'm sure I have setup everything correctly but there is no `await()` method on `Task<DocumentSnapshot>` like in the example of that link

Comment: You have to import the extension function from the library.